# contextlib fails occasionally

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I'd like to write help docs to a md file

```
>>> import re
>>> import contextlib
>>> file = open("regex_help.md", "w")
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
...     help(re)
```

However, "regex_help.md" is empty

```
>>> os.stat("regex_help.md").st_size
0
```

I remember it working yesterday.

```
>>> file.flush()
>>> os.stat("regex_help.md").st_size
1
```

file.flush() not working

Why it fails occasionally?

Comment: >>> file.flush()
>>> os.stat("regex_help.md").st_size
1
it's not working

Comment: It'd be much easier using `with open('regex_help.md', 'w') as fout: pydoc.doc(re, output=fout)`...

Comment: contextlib is universal, pydoc.doc not working for non-builtins @JonClements

Comment: It'll work on anything that `help` works on... as `help` calls `pydoc.doc`...

Comment: file.flush() working for pydoc. thank you @JonClements ^_^

Comment: Use a `with` block if that's your complete example - then you get exception handling and closing for free...

Comment: Separately, it's a very, very bad practice to name variables the same as built-ins

Comment: "file" is a buitin? @MatthewLDaniel

Comment: My pseudo-apologies, it seems [`file` is only a builtin in 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) but my observation stands (I've seen plenty of variables named `list` over my career, too)

Comment: thank you very much for the instruction. @MatthewLDaniel